# Getting a broken image string when converting gallery photo to BASE64 with Base64.EncodeString [Android] [Java]

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, base64

When converting a gallery photo from an activity with the Base64 Encoder, I get a faulty Base64 String. When using a site to test this, it's a broken image. My ExpressAPI gives me a validation error on the string aswell when trying to post this string.

I've already tried using different Bitmap variants like a Factory etc.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //call super
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        InputStream imageStream = null;
        try {
            imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        encodedString = encodeImage(selectedImage);
    }
```

```
 private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d(encImage, "Image:");
        return encImage;

    }
```

I obviously expect a Base64 String, but instead, I get this:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB: AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAONA1wDASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQQDAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAQFBgcICQoBAgML/8QAhRAAAAEHBwgGBQYHBg4M
CQEZAQACAwQFESEGBzFBUWHwCBRxgZGhscEJEhMk0eEKFSM08Ro5UpKXuBYiM0RXctgXMkNUgtIY
GSU4OkJid3iIorK3wjZWWFlkaHOVlrTU4iY1dHV2ttXW1ygqN1VmlJintbPyJ0VGR0hTZXmFhoeo
xMbH/8QAGwEBAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQFBgEDAgf/xABIEQACAAIGBwYEBQMDAgUEAwEAAQQR
ITFBUWGRAhRxgaHB8BKCorHR4QWS0vEiMkJSYgMGchWywhY1JDRUVfIjJUXiE0NTc//aAAwDAQAC EQMRAD8A7+CCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCAC
CCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACC
CCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCC
CACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCC
ACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCA
CCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCAC
CCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACC
CCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCC
CACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCC
ACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCA
CCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCAC
CCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACC
CCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCC
CACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCC
ACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCACCCCAqOdOdGSEzM2s4M7U4zTMk3Iia6R0opwpYtmHVZcn
pKMMZSyjSC+IgahRif1QcCURE3rGiACGlHoTZZZSuVlJmfPpD8oSXcvEEm8qCcBuIMnDJ7aEo22M
30zUykm0hyJSFEr9QxFnDTWgWRzgQRowSIEyI0wEicEiDHz0oGe2VTIyUZl8jWbYw0ZysuOe+T82
Cv1DRHsVcTkYpTzjniBpqZOcgRR6oPQInCInR6JJiZoJJ5PczE1cyUi1XM5KTTyDk3N2wDRF4gxp
MsBCqoBChxoig6wgLxA4BiQHOj0C2XjlZ5YWUt0l0jcoidhBOJJqYecWT7CmpVEUjGBJ05kKq1Ku
e9CsmmirAaIiKJnqRhoHQAxUQIjjzEBhxpdS5cWvotP9eB0yf99aQ/8ApGyhC7SiAC5aMrPLpytZ
ufSDsjrIrkVO0mY+TlOvNoxGrLiboJHyCaqVrJUqCfQ1IBq4kNFeQGH+r1E0T3GpgBUVjzkfaoEf
V6ly4tMuv+ywOj5/vUTV/wCZlAkBsU6WCfmfHo7cqzI9y91acacJfyJW3KX+h3yxJqPwpTNGbSSC
vLDtBkhPOdJo/roxW1cOuiSnIj+1NAxEkSI0Ip3H9CrOaTMbCgptJlrKqvMpdUQaCivKR5nqpfMP
e494dYBNeBpwPOH8V4iLzRNDC/pKsl9Wyx8hDKbycczNWmvOBNa3fwOMMcIfh3JnqSum0OeIxdLS
TcmxOvoB7gHXF6OJlVpcqPo0ZtFOVp+dS5ye262snyVCQAA0T0jOSKQIDj4PPOSIkqM0DxERFCgM
AIOcAwqOUBl2ndPm1cnJInnBN6PtTmbMauaDNmxDZuQlMM0Zq8agCWZsmgWOp60A1yoC/wBicc5V
ihEDCXdOBlF9IBk/SkyHgyGEsv8ANJwp4mux58jZBzQMOdA46TJgSW7I9YRJzAEw8Tki2jEwOuJ5
vUE9Mf1RRGZYq3SnyDX+lJafRbmzXy0Nl+oTchLgJ1gW2F6j7D8Gvwq7EFYRBKBwIPZmmAaaIJfx
83f7EvnpKulNkF0bDVyamPLebCWU5I5S84zWm0YAyTaLBZQyaTGIUKXrnnphEUgOOR9UTRE4BMER
S9oImogNuBBBBAc2XpI2WplP5CeSXMnONkpzkmTZy1lTPwxpFNNtpZIsCUINNhpJv5VrAmmmLIJD
EZoJkSFIaBhgGGnIzAMNNNRI39EEllpYWpNMBbWwAF1ZYLEXVwa/x0BiU5wWu6z6AgNYw5R/TB/6
wrJu/wALtif6E51yzJylemwZU0k4yvklZGOS1O3l75UMgWUxwl1JCZVE2zpEzagKMDHSrlQlQpgO
ADDRNABDqj1gNSCKM3qkB0OEFyTt70ifKQyYpQsJB0ivRWT6ZMk3zfXhZRk6DHlYjlArI0gB+IlS
IwRIUqU0DnHHIwXTX0B2cBDptmYnfmyygZq5FTxzOyqY0uZsZwZOMeUUjJWM4esx2qwzhDqHmHC4
TRAOsHVE1xpwuDrGmgJwGj/JOyg8viW3TZ5b8xs8J8uEORhNpNk2GnMMot2ac1gyMTyjOlBMWEng
k9OUZJZDnwGKq61FjsEyZYNMPPTrZpiVOYBw7z5050ZITMzazgztTjNMyTciJrpHSinCli2YdVly
ekowxlLKNIL4iBqFGJ/VBwJRETesaIAIa6Jg+lJkDP30juUv0dLEmvllJyW+TFJFpS1lDLporrBP
YMpDQSSKR9mrI0QikRGifOQiSGgcckRo0gddJ+J1zg1y+lAz2yqZGSjMvkazbGGjOVlxz3yfmwV+
oaI9iricjFKecc8QNNTJzkCKPVB6BE4RE6IGQfQmyyylcrKTM+fSH5Qku5eIJN5UE4DcQZOGT20J
RtsZvpmplJNpDkSkKJX6hiLOGmtAsjnAgjRgkQJkRpgJE4JEGkSZvKk6ejLmy8MvTJ0yQcuaambi
TuTNPHOgpMlTnvm+mjX1BTkQrTwJJLyUBhrkmcmpZXFtMCsqpTj1leTpU6c80e0TJFhKHX7XJiZo
JJ5PczE1cyUi1XM5KTTyDk3N2wDRF4gxpMsBCqoBChxoig6wgLxA4BiXJD6PN88R01n99WdP7yEr
SAvn+g49LH/30DIv/wChknP2BSP6Dj0sf/fQMi//AKGSc/YFLrOIIDmZnHyaemeU+jIyh0c8uWcr
tvLfmtnCXJ9pkZwsmJbPYzOb0gZNybV0v7jEoZOhIubZBmqyKNsJkyM9VTpE5ydTAxcSChTJFzal
0ZGW/JnpBsjCafKVZmYqUoJTM31XOfJ9nOdJedCTIIglXJw4x7xORHmgcAg4wE
```

Look at this request: [request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93jyJ.png)

This is the request:

```
private void uploadMeme() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url = "Hiding this for personal reasons";
        final MemeCreateActivity activity = (MemeCreateActivity) getActivity();
        assert activity != null;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("Title", title);
            jsonBody.put("Longtitude", activity.getLon());
            jsonBody.put("Lattitude", activity.getLat());
            jsonBody.put("Picture", activity.getEncodedString());
            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();
            Log.d(mRequestBody, "Request:");
            JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    activity.nextView();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    parseVolleyError(error);
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    //Sets Request headers
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + activity.getUser().getJwt());
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java decodes the Bitmap with spaces in the base64 string, try this: `encodedString.replaceAll("\\s+","");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("EncodedImage: ", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}
```

Use below code in onActivityResult()

```
InputStream imageStream = null;
        try {
            imageStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        encodeTobase64(yourSelectedImage);
```

Comment: Possible you can't show whole string in logs! or may be your image is corrupted.

Comment: I've tried different images. But here is the string: https://pastebin.com/ebFV1LSh

Comment: yes, log have a limit, you should try to save the data in a txt file directly to try to convert it back

Comment: I put the function to write to api in the original post aswell

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the bitmap via the path of the file you picked :

*In your onActivityResult*

```
Uri targetUri = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(targetUri,
    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
//getting the actual path of the file
String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

//your encoding function is ok
encodedString = encodeImage(selectedImage);
```

Comment: This gives me a permission error: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20190404-WA0009.jpg (Permission denied)

Comment: I fixed the permission, but I still get a faulty base64 string back. Whenever I try to decode it, I just get a broken image

Comment: I use the exact same code you use for `encodeImage()` and it works for me, maybe your decoder is faulty ? or you have the wrong file format ? (i.e. trying to convert a PNG file but you use `bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos)`

Comment: I just use WhatsApp images which are already compressed I believe, they are JPG

Comment: Check my request image in the original post

Comment: try in the process to put the bitmap in an imageview to see is the bitmap seems correct or not at all, because this should work, and the base64 you linked look like it is ok

Comment: So the base64 I posted doesn't work on decoder sites: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
As for the imageview, I already got that and it works fine

Comment: i tested my images with my generated base64, it doesn't work on this site but they are successfully sent, received, decoded and saved with an asp.net api. I tried two sites like that to test and it doesn't seems to work on these sites

Answer (score 0):

Right.. I've found the answer. Basically, Android thought it was funny to insert multiple whitespaces into my string.

By doing this, you can remove it all:

```
activity.getEncodedString().replaceAll("\s+","")
```